# Absolute value in postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm looking for the best way to get the sum of the absolute values with Ruby and Postgres.

I've tried the line below but it provides the wrong sum:

```
Day.last.transactions.sum  { |r| r.value_cents.abs }
```

Comment: Wrong in what way? This seems pretty straightforward even though it does pull everything into Rails and does the summing there instead of in the db which would be quicker.

Comment: Calling `.to_a` on your transactions collection might help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with Postgres like this which is much quicker than pulling everything into Rails and doing the calculation there.

```
Day.last.transactions.pluck('sum(abs(value_cents))::integer')
```